# When using NotePad++ how do I use a RegEx to split a line into two?

Tags: regex, notepad++

I have a .txt file with a lot of records (lines of data) in it. Out of those, one particular line is in the below format

```
keyword_one: Some data for this keyword_one keyword_two:Some data for this keyword_two
```

I want the output to be split into two lines as below:

```
keyword_one: Some data for this keyword_one
keyword_two:Some data for this keyword_two
```

I know the "key" or  "hint" is to search for the string "keyword_two:" and put everything starting from that till End of Line to next new line.

But, how do I do that in? If anyone can provide a solution using RegEx, I can use it easily to replace all such occurrences using my NOTEPAD++

Comment: Can you guarantee that keywords don't appear inside data, or the : is only used as a keyword:value separator? If not, it looks like you need a cleaner data source.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Look for `keyword_two:` and replace with `\nkeyword_two`

http://img189.imageshack.us/img189/3096/screenshot20111018at122.png

You don't need to use regex for this since you're doing it in Notepad

Answer (score 2):

You don't need regex for this. Just replace all occurrences of `" keyword_two:"` with `"\nkeyword _two:"` (without quotes, where `\n` is a newline).